# Css best practices: styles specific to one single dom element

Tags: css

What is the preferred way to store styles very specific to one single dom element? In a separate css file, or inline in the style attribute in the html file?

I'll give you an example. This is the css i currently have in a css file. Titlebar, product title, product description, and category image are elements which all need very specific styling and I will never reuse the styles anywhere else. I am very tempted to add them inline and only leave the more general styles in the css file. Should I do this? Why/why not?

```
#titlebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 141px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 38px;
  line-height: 38px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #666;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#product-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia;
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#product-description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 210px;
  left: 110px;
  width: 190px;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#category-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 186px;
  left: 43px;
  width: 52px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally use an external stylesheet (or several) because they can be cached by the browser.

Using inline styles is a bad idea. It reduces maintainability and separation of code and presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes for general styles, so you can apply them to more than one object without having to rewrite them in your stylesheet.

Use ids for specifics.

And def use external sheets if you can manage it.